# Does the amount of ETH in staking have to be exactly 32 ETH or only at least 32 ETH?

Tags: eth-2.0, staking

The amount of ETH to be put at stake in phase 0 of Ethereum 2.0 is at least 32ETH but, is it also a maximum? I know that the possibilities of being chosen to propose blocks depends in the amount of ETH at stake but I don't know if at phase 0 only fixed stake validators are allowed.

Comment: If I remember correctly it should be a multiply of 32. So 40 would give you the same rewards as 32. But don't remember for sure so won't leave a real answer.

Comment: Some more context might be useful here. For example, a link to the document which lists this specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Validator Submit deposit specs](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/validator.md#submit-deposit):

> A validator can only be activated when total deposits for the
> validator pubkey meet or exceed `MAX_EFFECTIVE_BALANCE`.

You can find this variable in the [Beacon Chain phase0 specs document](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#gwei-values):

```
| `MAX_EFFECTIVE_BALANCE` | `Gwei(2**5 * 10**9)` (= 32,000,000,000) |
```

From the [The beacon chain post on Ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/eth2/the-beacon-chain/#validation), about Validation:

> The bigger your stake, the more often you'll be chosen to propose
> shard blocks. However 32ETH is effectively the max, so having more
> than 32ETH staked does not change the amount you are selected, but
> having less than 32 does.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. In fact it can even be less than 32 eth; in the [Eth2 Deposit Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa#code) the conditions to enable a deposit are the following :

```
// Check deposit amount
require(msg.value >= 1 ether, "DepositContract: deposit value too low");
require(msg.value % 1 gwei == 0, "DepositContract: deposit value not multiple of gwei");
uint deposit_amount = msg.value / 1 gwei;
require(deposit_amount <= type(uint64).max, "DepositContract: deposit value too high");
```

So the minimum amount seems to be 1 ether. However, by looking at the [spec](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#is_eligible_for_activation_queue) you can see that the condition to be eligible as a validator is to meet the condition `validator.effective_balance == MAX_EFFECTIVE_BALANCE` where `MAX_EFFECTIVE_BALANCE` is equal to 32 eth.

For a better understanding of the life cycle of a validator I recommend reading [this](https://notes.ethereum.org/7CFxjwMgQSWOHIxLgJP2Bw#A-note-on-Ethereum-20-phase-0-validator-lifecycle) website.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at current validators, all of them have either exactly 32 ETH or little more than that - https://ethscan.org/validators